# database upgrade required but prohibited realm swift

Tags: ios, swift, database, realm, realm-studio

trying to open .realm file via Realm Studio on MAC but Screen appears
including " database upgrade required but prohibited. " " no schema selected "

[this screen appears when i open .realm file via Realm Swift](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oe0BJ.png)

tried to open the file via realm swift but it gives "Cannot find Encryption Key"

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Welcome to SO. That error could be due to a lot of things but generally indicates the underlying database version of Realm vs Realm Studio is not compatible. Please update the *question* with the version of Realm, Realm Studio, XCode and OS. Is the Realm encrypted? Is this a local only, partition or flex Realm?

Comment: realm studio is 14.0.1
realm is 10.24.0
Xcode 13.2.1 (13C100)
mac is 12.6.3 (21G419)

Comment: As a guess, you've got an older Realm and XCode and a new version of Realm Studio. It's possible the lock file formats are incompatible. Can you try upgrading your Realm to a more current version?

Comment: Any updates? Also facing the same issue on latest realm version. Studio 12 opens it, but not 14.